# Laravel 5.2 Route/href

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my route.php i have this code

```
 Route::group(array('prefix' => 'athlete'), function () {
        Route::get('test', 'AthleteController@index')->name('test');
    });
```

In my controller AthleteController

```
public function index()
{
    return view('Frontend/views/athlete/profil');
}
```

In my view i create href, but not work

```
<a href="{{route('test')}}">Test</a>
```

I have this error :

> FatalErrorException in c8dad5722499b68e914f212daece129d539cff9e.php line 100: syntax error, unexpected 'test' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

I use Laravel 5.2

Comment: Can you add your entire view and how you load it from the controller method? This code is ok but there is probably something else that generates this error.

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` and check how Your route was published.

Comment: It's not a route issue, as @TheFallen mentioned, probably the view has some missing closing '' quote

Answer (score 0):

Open `storage/framework/views/c8dad5722499b68e914f212daece129d539cff9e.php` and look at line 100. You have a simple syntax error. It's giving you a hint `unexpected 'test' ... expecting ',' or ';'`. Looking at this cached view you should then know which corresponding view it is and what corresponding line as well. Which I imagine is `'Frontend/views/athlete/profil'` according to your listed controller action.

Answer (score 0):

What's on line 100 like the error message says?

Your code looks fine except for this:

```
return view('Frontend/views/athlete/profil');
```

I'm guessing it's not finding a view with that name and instead you meant return

```
view('Frontend/views/athlete/profile');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
<a href="{{route('test')}}">Test</a>
```

To

```
<a href="{{url('/test')}}">Test</a>
```

Hope this work for you